# Other uses of 中

Tags: grammar

What’s the difference between 办法 and 办法中？

I found the latter in:

他告诉我三百六十种办法中的每一种。

But I cannot make sense of why 中 is in this sentence.

I read a few answers related to 中 here but I’m not quite sure “within” or “in” is the right answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

中 can also mean "among" (short for 之中)

三百六十种办法[**中**] = [**amon**g] the 360 ways

Another example:

化学元素[**中**]，鉄是最稳定的 = [**Among**] the chemical elements, iron is the most stable

在鸡群[**中**]，一只白鹤自然十分突出 = [**In**/ **among**] the flock of chickens, a white crane is naturally very prominent

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 之中.

化學元素"之中"，鉄是最稳定的 and 化學元素"中"，鉄是最稳定的 have the same meaning.